# Android Studio: Webview Custom Css

Tags: android, css

I'm trying to make a webview app of `Facebook.com` with a custom css to change a few things. I already have the `style.css` in my assets folder but it doesn't work.

**Here is my code:**

```
private WebView webView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);

    WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    String htmlData = "<link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"style.css\" />";

    webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("http://facebook.com", htmlData, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
}
```